# Resources utilization of app service plan per app service basis

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an app service plan having multiple app services. we want resource utilization of app service plan per app service so we can divide the cost among all the app service.

Is there a way to attribute costs and resources on a per app service basis?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Diagnose and Solve Problems` in your web app and search for Metrics Per Instance as shown below:

[image]

This way you can check the metrics for individual app level. For the cost part you will be charged as per the no. of instance in an App service Plan no matters how many apps running within that App Service Plan.